# Java Sending a short String via Socket in a high frequency

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, packet

I am trying to make an application to control DMX Channels. For this I have an ESP8266 which takes a String as an input like "2.255", where the first integer is the DMX Channel and the second integer the value.

For my PC I wrote a method that first builds the string and then sens it to the IP Address of the ESP8266 via a Socket.

```
for(DMXChannel c : list){
if(lastvalue.get(c.getChannelID() - 1) != c.getValue()){

     try {
            String msg = c.getChannelID() + "." + c.getValue();;
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            InetAddress ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip); //IP Address is "192.168.4.1"

            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            sendData = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ipaddr, 8888);

            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            clientSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }
}
```

This works fine but I have a problem when I am trying to do a fade. The frequency of this piece of code seems to be too slow.

Does anyone have a "faster" solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you could do to speed up the code:

1. Do not call `getByName` for an IP address. This involves DNS, but DNS is not needed for an IP address. Instead call `getByAddress`. If you do need to call getByName, call it only once and cache the answer.
2. Do not open, close, reopen, etc. the socket each time. Just keep it open.